# How to sign in firebase users who originally signed up via phone number authentication

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I'm implementing Firebase phone number authentication in my Unity app. I am able to verify, create, and sign in a Firebase user using the phone number and verification code received via SMS.

However, the SMS code is one-time use and I don't know how to automatically sign in the user the next time they run the app.

I have tried saving the verification id and code and signing them back in using the initial verification details but Firebase indicates that the code is expired, as expected.

````
    {
        PhoneAuthProvider provider = PhoneAuthProvider.GetInstance(firebaseAuth);
        Credential credential =
            provider.GetCredential(PlayerPrefs.GetString("FirebaseVerificationId"), PlayerPrefs.GetString("FirebaseVerificationCode") );

        firebaseAuth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " +
                               task.Exception);
                return;
            }

            FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
            Global.Instance.firebaseUser = newUser;
            Debug.Log("User signed in successfully");
            // This should display the phone number.
            Debug.Log("Phone number: " + newUser.PhoneNumber);
            // The phone number providerID is 'phone'.
            Debug.Log("Phone provider ID: " + newUser.ProviderId);
            PostSignIn();
        });
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking it. Firebase does the work for you. The authenticated user info is persisted in Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser. You just need to check if it's not null.